# Error trying to return field value from Status object

Tags: python, twitter

I have the following code:

```
tweet = random.choice(result)
pprint(tweet)
tweet_id = tweet['id']
```

the first line is working because, pprint(tweet) is printing:

```
Status(ID=1228151646292762624, ScreenName=None, Created=Fri Feb 14 02:59:05 +0000 2020, Text='one person followed me // automatically checked by [REDACTED])
```

to the console. The problem is in tweet_id = tweet['id']. It's giving me error:

```
Task hello.tasks.my_task[13181b70-70a0-44cc-94d7-87f173fbe3cb] raised unexpected: TypeError("'Status' object is not subscriptable",)
```

Obviously status object doesn't function like a dict. So how do you get field 'ID' out from it?

Comment: it can't access the id property, you need to loop through each tweet,. pprint just print out your objects

Comment: my question is how do you loop through the tweet. Could you please provide some code?

Comment: i don't want to write a simple code as simple as a for loop, that what you need to work on

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by loop through each tweet. Status IS a tweet. i just need to access the individual members of this tweet.

Comment: seems like your object don't have `__getitem__` so you can change `tweet['id']` to `tweet('id') or tweet.ID'. Your tweet actually returning 1 object, as i don''t know what the random.choice() code is.

Comment: not working unfortunately..